# Getting Javascript to insert values into my textboxes (AJAX!)

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I have this code, which I am trying to use to make it update my form text boxes when I select a different drop down user.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("useruname").onchange = function() {
var selecteduname = this.value;
}

var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc()
{

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
  {
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
}

function updateAdduser()
{loadXMLDoc();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
var fields = JSON.parse(json);
Object.keys(fields).forEach(function (name) {
var input = document.getElementsByName(name);
input.value = fields[name];
});
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajaxuseradd.psp?=", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
<form action="adduser.psp" method="get">
<fieldset>
<label for="uname">Username:</label>
<select name="uname" id="useruname" onChange="updateAdduser();">
<%
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "login", "password", "somethingelse")
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("""SELECT user from employees;""")

tup = c.fetchall()

tupstr = str(tup)

tupstr = tupstr.replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(")", "").replace(",,", ",").replace("'", "").replace("' ", "'").replace(", ", ",")

tupstr = tupstr.rstrip(",")

numlist = tupstr.split(",")

optionlist =  ['<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (x, x) for x in numlist]

options = "\n".join(optionlist)

%>


 <%= options %>

 </select>

 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" />
</fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: ... So what is it doing that it shouldn't, or not doing that it should? Please be more precise about what you mean by "update my form text boxes". Also, I assume you're using some kind of templating engine here, and the Python in the middle of that snippet is actually executed and the results interpolated? You might want to mention your templating engine as well. As for the actual AJAX work, have you considered using a library such as jQuery?

Comment: It should be filling in the textboxes with values from the server. I.e. they'll come preloaded, when you select an option value with that user's information, which can then be edited and resubmitted.

I am not using a templating engine, only mod_python with Python Server Pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would seriously consider moving to using a client javascript library like **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)**.

Your code would be simplified to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#useruname").change = function() {
    var selecteduname = this.value;
}


function updateAdduser()
{
    var fields = null;
    $.ajax(url: "ajaxuseradd.psp?=",
           dataType = 'json',
        success: function(data){
          fields = data;
          Object.keys(fields).forEach(function (name) {
              var input = $(name);
              input.value = fields[name];
          });
      }
    });  
}    
</script>

<form action="adduser.psp" method="get">
<fieldset>
<label for="uname">Username:</label>
<select name="uname" id="useruname" onChange="updateAdduser();">
<%
import MySQLdb

db =
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("""SELECT user from employees;""")

tup = c.fetchall()

tupstr = str(tup)

tupstr = tupstr.replace("(", "").replace("'", "").replace(")", "").replace(",,", ",").replace("'", "").replace("' ", "'").replace(", ", ",")

tupstr = tupstr.rstrip(",")

numlist = tupstr.split(",")

optionlist =  ['<option value="%s">%s</option>' % (x, x) for x in numlist]

options = "\n".join(optionlist)

%>


 <%= options %>

 </select>

 </fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" />
</fieldset>
 <fieldset>
    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email">
</fieldset>
```